# Atomエディタで、LaTeX文書中で一度用いた単語を自動補完したい。

Tags: atom-editor, latex

Atomエディタを使って、LaTeXで文書作成をしているのですが、
文書中で一度用いた英単語を自動補完してくれる機能はないでしょうか？

Atomにはautocompleteの機能はありますが、
language-latexというパッケージを入れても、
syntaxなものを自動補完してくれるだけで、
文書中で用いた英単語については補完してくれません。

どなたかご教授いただければと思います。

Comment: ちょっとどんな文章を書いているのかわからないので日本語、英語がなど複数言語が混在した文章になっているのか、それとも英語だけなどの文章になっているのか、すこしヒントをくれませんか？

たぶん英語やアルファベットだけならばGoogleIMEなどのIMEが解決してくれるはずです。日本語や英語が混ざり合った文章ならば、いま調べたのですがもうすこし時間をかけてサーチしなければわからないかもしれないです(´・ω・｀)

Comment: 英語の文章を書いています。日本語ならIMEで可能なのですが、IMEで英語の自動補完はできるのでしょうか？Atomを使ってPythonでプログラミングしている時には、一度自分で定義した変数名などはすべて自動補完されるので、それと同じことがLaTeXファイルを扱っている時にもできれば良いのですが、うまくいきません。

Comment: ★☆★☆★調査します★☆★☆★

Comment: 調査中。。。
https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=word+prediction+software+for+pc&biw=1261&bih=562&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTy7KBhqnKAhXLJJQKHYNBDgUQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=word+prediction+

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分も探してみます。

Comment: 結果：該当するソフトウェアやアドオン無し

１５分間、考えられる単語を総当りで検索したんですがみつかりませんでした。唯一、ねこさんが欲しがりそうな感じのソフトウェアを発見しましたが、有償のソフトウェアでした。http://donjohnston.com/cowriter/

どうやらねこさんが欲しがっている機能は「type prediction」 もしくは「word prediction」という分野の入力アシストソフトウェアということまでは突き止めました

Comment: 推測なのですが、英語などのアルファベットの入力補完というのは基本的に多くのユーザーにとって需要がないツールなのかもしれません

Comment: なぜなら、PCのキーボードでは熟練したユーザーならば単語を高速にタイピングが可能であり、タッチタイピングが難しいスマホ入力やガラケー方式の入力では入力補完が存在しますが、PCでは多くのユーザーに求められていないためそもそも入力補完のソフトウェアの開発があまりされていないと推測されます

Comment: 需要はあまりないのですね…残念です。タイプミスしやすい専門用語が多く出てくる文章を書く仕事をしているので、入力補完がほしかったのです。いろいろと探してくださってありがとうございました。

Comment: ミススペルがあるから補完が欲しかったんですねわかりました。

たぶんなんですが、ねこさんが不便に思ってくれるところは時間が解決してくれると思います。ミスススペルのチェックをするプロググラムはもうすでに出来上ががっていますが、ミススペルのチェックのプログラムはPCに保存したローカルな辞書を使っているんですよ。でもいまの時代はほとんどのデータがインターネットにつながっていて、辞書はネットから１分ごとに更新し続ければ「三代目JB」といった新しい単語にも対応できますし、そうすればミススペルペルもグッと減るんじゃないでしょうか。特にこれからは人工知能が入力をアシスタントしてくれますので、文章の精査や脱字誤字のチェックもうまくいくと思いますよ〜

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`autocomplete-plus`パッケージの設定を開いて、`Default Provider`の設定を`Symbol`から`Fuzzy`に変更し、Atomを再起動してください。これにより、LaTeXのキーワード以外の単語も候補に出現します。

[image: https://gyazo.com/301bb45b91de15f0252cc5853bcde072]

Comment: Fuzzyに設定して無事解決しました。一度使用した専門用語や人名もすべて自動補完されて便利になりました。ありがとうございます。